# No Ubuntu logo during startup

Tags: boot

i have just installed Ubuntu 10.10 on a Sony vaio but, their is no Ubuntu logo on boot all i get is a black screen some writing saying an error and then straight to the login screen. i really like the boot screen and if their is anyway to get the computer boot normally i would like to hear. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this problem is related to the nvidia drivers, [this script](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/script-to-fix-ubuntu-plymouth-for.html) might help you (fixed this issue for me)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I had a similar problem. I was seeing the color and all, but it was ASCII graphics. I followed the steps mentioned here, and now I am fine:

http://open-help.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-fix-ugly-plymouth-logo-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: This worked for me. But you do have to do a bit of experimentation for finding which resolution works best for your system.